# Divided and combined Node Text from result table?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

how can I add ";" a divide and combine the following text from the row? ..whilst keeping the existing programming structure.

divided

within tag text "**HammarbyvsOstersunds**", I want to separate into **Hammarby** ; **vs** ; **Ostersunds**;.

combined:

within tag text "**Expected**;*In*;**Play**;*start*;**selling**;*time:*" to **Expected In Play start selling time:** ；

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")

table = ['; '.join(["; ".join( j.text.split(" ")) for j in i.find_elements_by_class_name('couponRow') if j.text]) for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="todds"]//div[@class="couponTable"]') if i.text]

for line in table:
    print line
driver.close()
```

output:

```
Monday;Matches
MON;41;HammarbyvsOstersunds;Expected;In;Play;start;selling;time:
10/07;01:00;1.85;3.50;3.35
Tuesday;Matches
TUE;1;FrancevsBelgium;Expected;In;Play;start;selling;time:
11/07;02:00;2.38;2.82;2.95
Wednesday;Matches
WED;1;CroatiavsEngland;Expected;In;Play;start;selling;time:
12/07;02:00;3.45;2.80;2.15
```

expected result:

```
Monday; Matches；
MON;41;Hammarby； vs； Ostersunds;Expected In Play start selling time: ； 10/07;01:00;1.85;3.50;3.35
Tuesday; Matches；
TUE;1;France；vs；Belgium; Expected In Play start selling time:；11/07;02:00;2.38;2.82;2.95
Wednesday;Matches
WED;1;Croatia；vs；England;Expected In Play start selling time: ；12/07;02:00;3.45;2.80;2.15
```

Comment: What about using regex for python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested, you should split your task into smaller manageable pieces of code.

I played a bit around with your code, but it's arguably too hard to get the perfect result out of it. Here is what I got:

```
table = ['; '.join([" ".join( j.text.split(" ")) for j in i.find_elements_by_class_name('couponRow') if j.text]) for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="todds"]//div[@class="couponTable"]') if i.text]
lines = [' ; '.join(t.split('\n')) for t in table]
result = [re.sub(r"([A-Z]\w+)vs([A-Z]\w+)", r'; \1 vs \2;', l, 0, re.MULTILINE) for l in lines]
```

Result:

```
['Tuesday Matches; TUE 1 ; France vs Belgium; Expected In Play start selling time: ; 11/07 02:00 --- --- ---',
 'Wednesday Matches; WED 1 ; Croatia vs England; Expected In Play start selling time: ; 12/07 02:00 --- --- ---']
```

Not great but maybe good enough..

The main problem is that your selector is a bit broad and selects the raw text.
You could try to zero in on the nodes you are actually interested, like

```
teams = [team.text for team in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="cteams"]/span/span[@class="teamname"]')]
```

.. and so on